# What is a linear regression in which each point is not exact and have been drawn from a distribution in statistical literature?

Tags: regression

Assume we have a linear regression where each data point is not exact. For example, it may be inaccurate and we assume it has been drawn from a distribution centered at the data location.

What is this setting is called in statistical literature and what is an important reference for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called [errors in variables models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models).

Comment: Do you know of an important article or book of these works?

Comment: Check the references on the wikipedia article.

Comment: Also see *Model II* regression (there are a number of other relevant terms you may find helpful)